# Successive calculation of coefficient of variation

Tags: python, loops, statistics

I'm having a long list of values which is triple indexed `(i,j,t)`. For all `i` in `I` and `j` in `J` I have to extract all `t` values and calculate the coefficient of variation (cv) successively. The length of the cv list ist `len(I)*len(J)`. Then I plot the cv list and check whether the cv converged to sum number.
Right now I am looping, which is rather inefficient (see example). Is there another possibility which avoids the loops?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iN = 10
jN = 10
tN = 20

I = range(iN)
J = range(jN)
T = range(tN)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([I,J,T])
data = np.random.normal(loc=1, size=iN*jN*tN)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['value'])


values_lst = []
cv_lst = []
for i in I:
    for j in J:
        values_lst.extend(df.loc[(i,j,slice(None)), 'value'])
        
        sd = np.std(values_lst, ddof=1)
        mean = np.mean(values_lst)
        
        cv_lst.append(sd/mean)
        
plt.plot(cv_lst)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Im posting this in the assumtion that you can easily extract your data into a (i,j,t) sized numpy array. In that case you can let numpy do its magic:

```
cv_list = np.std(data, axis=2, ddof=1)/np.mean(data, axis=2)
```

`axis=2` means you do your mean or std over your axis t. The result is still a 2D array you can reshape or flatten as you like.